# Solvent Base Oil on my leather steering wheel

Tags: car, citroen

I have a Citeron C1 and used a solvent oil base odorizer to clean my leather steering wheel and its ruined it, it looks like a moldy mildew green. How can i restore the colour?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have damaged the original finish.

So best buy a leather cover and the best ones you can get are sewn on.

That's what I m getting for mine - not that it has been damaged by solvent - a damp cloth is sufficient for cleaning but age and use has worn it down in places (220,000Km is the cause).